# dynamic content with ajax (ruby on rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I am using Rails and jquery, and I need a dynamic content with ajax.

But I don't know how to get the current user ID

For example the url is www.mywebsite.com/users/**20**

In my javascript file I need the user ID (20)

```
$.get("/users/<%= **20** %>.json", function(data)
      {

      }, "json");
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the rails variable value to a javascript variable in your view file like

> "<%= javascript_tag "var userId = #{@current_user.id};" %>"

and access the variable inside js file wherever you want.

Answer (score 5):

Generally i put a `hidden` field with the `id` somewhere in the page, where i can easily access with `$("#user_id")` on the javascript file, then the request would be something like this:

```
var id = $("#user_id").val();
$.get("/users/"+id+".json", function(data) { }, "json");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get("/users/<%= params[:id] %>.json", function(data)
  {

  }, "json");
```

Should do the trick.

Include the snippet into the .erb file or create a .js.erb partial with this.

Comment: True, added more info in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Lots of choices:

1. If you have a current user object with the id (*Note*: this must be in a file ending with `.js.erb`):

   `$.get("/users/<%= @current_user.id %>.json", function(data){...}, "json");`
2. If you don't want to use a `.js.erb` file, but still need the value to be set somewhere on the page, then set a data-attribute or hidden input with the id value.
3. If you have the id value in the url (as in the current url you are on looks like `www.mywebsite.com/users/20` and you want the GET request to use 20 as the value), you can use `document.url` or `window.location.href` and some string manipulation to get the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    <%= escape_javascript(params[:id]) %>
I'm not completely sure if escape_javascript is necessary or will help.